# What is the event for ASIHTTPRequest to get the http header?

Tags: iphone

I have checked the source codes of ASIHTTPRequest and could not make sure which one is.

Thanks

interdev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reading the documentation http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use

Look for "Reading response headers"

Comment: Thanks

the the codes

Reading response headers
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request startSynchronous];
NSString *poweredBy = [[request responseHeaders] objectForKey:@"X-Powered-By"];
NSString *contentType = [[request responseHeaders] objectForKey:@"Content-Type"];

are for Synchronous

Comment: Yes, the *example* is for synchronous, but that doesn't mean you can't use the `[request respsonseHeaders]` call in your `requestFinished:` delegate method.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I am confused. 'requestFinished:' is only triggered when a request finishied. If I want to get the size of a file before download, how can I do? Maybe I have misunderstand something.

Comment: Maybe you could do it in a downloadProgressDelegate (with showAccurateStatus=Yes). Once you start getting progress updates, presumably the headers have already been downloaded.